# Laravel - injecting a class with unknown argument

Tags: php, testing, laravel

I'm trying to inject a class via my controller constructor so I can test it. However, the class I'm using comes from an [external package](https://github.com/koraktor/steam-condenser-php/blob/master/lib/SteamCondenser/Community/SteamId.php). The class `SteamId` requires an argument to be passed.

```
$steam = new \SteamCondenser\Community\SteamId('1234');
```

So, although this works, it is not testable or mockable. I get the id required from the URL once the user has "logged in", so I cannot bind the class to an instance of SteamId on boot, since I don't know the ID then. E.g

```
App::bind('SteamCondenser\Community\SteamId', function() {
    return new SteamCondenser\Community\SteamId('1234');
});

class SteamController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct(\SteamCondenser\Community\SteamId $steam) {
        $this->steam = $steam;
    }
```

I don't the ID until a method on my `SteamController` has been called.

How do I get around this, so I'm able to test and mock the class?

Comment: Do you want to test the `SteamId` class or your controller? Because if you only want to test the controller you could create a mock of the `SteamId` class

Comment: Test my controller, I just wasn't sure whether I had to inject it via the constructor. Just seems a really "icky" way of working this

Comment: Well dependency injection is recommended and especially makes testing easier. You can either mock the `SteamId` class (with [mockery](https://github.com/padraic/mockery) for example) or just use a static ID for testing

Comment: Thanks. I'm using PHPSpec, but I'm not really sure how I can mock it with that... Looking at examples it looks easier to mock with PHPUnit.